# localitics & comScore memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, iphone, comscore

I'm using Localitics and ComScore libs for collecting some statistic for my app. And I have a problem with memory leaks. If any body use such libs, and know how to solve this problem. Or, maybe, it's not a problem?

in more details: after, when i commented

```
//  [[LocalyticsSession sharedLocalyticsSession] startSession:LOCALYTICS_KEY];
//  [[CSComScore census] notifyStart:COMSCORE_ACCOUNT_ID andSecret:COMSCORE_SECRET];
```

in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in my appDelegate, all leaks disappear.

---

### update

1. comScore

   - I'm using only base functions: in app there no code related to comScore except "notifyStart".
2. localitics

   - I used http://www.localytics.com/documentation/iphone-integration/ for integration this lib. My appDelegate looks exactly as said in instruction. for loging i'm using -

   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [[LocalyticsSession sharedLocalyticsSession] tagScreen:@"Near Me."];
   //here I have warning: ... may not respond to ...
   }

here you have screen shot of my Performance tool:
[image]

hope it will help.

Comment: You need to tell us a bit more. What have you tried? Could you show us a bit more code? I haven't used those classes, but are they the only messages you can call? Do you send any more messages to those classes?

Comment: That warning concerns me. Is that definitely the correct method signature. You remembered the `import`?

Comment: I've checked. Strange, but I haven't found any errors in method signature, and all imports are done. So, could you please increase your vote. when i've corrected my question, it become more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten to remove my downvote

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exaclty what is wrong with your memory there. I use [touchwizards.com](https://touchwizards.com) for analysis, it has some great interaction analysis for iOS like heatmaps and more